# Calling a FORTRAN subroutine from C#

Tags: c#, fortran, pinvoke, dllimport

I want to import a FORTRAN DLL into visual C#. While I have done that with functions, the problem arises when I want to import a subroutine with multiple outputs. Here is a simple example:

---

**FORTRAN DLL:**

```
Subroutine MySub(a,b,x,y)

!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL, ALIAS:'MySub' :: MySub

Implicit None
Integer, INTENT(IN) :: a,b
Integer, INTENT(OUT) :: x,y

 y=a+b
 x=2*a+3*b
End Subroutine MySub
```

---

**C# Console App:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AlReTest
{
    class Program
    {
    [DllImport(@"D:\...\AltRetTest.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int MySub(int a, int b, [Out] int x, [Out] int y);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int a = 4;
        int b = 3;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        MySub(a, b, x, y);

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.WriteLine(MySub(a, b, x, y));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here are the answers that I get:
x=0, y=0, MySub(a, b, x, y)=17

I'm a bit new in Visual C# programming, but I think above results mean that the two statements i.e. 'a+b' and '2*a+3*b' have been calculated but not assigned to x and y, and the latter (2*a+3*b) has been assigned to the function MySub itself! I have used OutAttributes in C#, also Intent[In], Intent[Out] in FORTRAN, but none have changed the results. I would appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Which Fortran compiler are you using?

Comment: @ClickRick Read the comments on answer below, I use Compaq Visual Fortran 6.6. Problem solved by adding a reference attribute in my FORTRAN DLL.

Comment: As I saw (you answered that bit after I'd asked) but you & David clearly had it covered between you so didn't comment further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you I assumed that `INTENT(OUT)` would imply pass by reference. But it seems that is not the case. So you need to add the following to the FORTRAN to force pass by reference:

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: x,y
```

The correct declaration of the function on the C# side is:

```
[DllImport(...)]
public static extern void MySub(int a, int b, out int x, out int y);
```

Call it like this:

```
MySub(a, b, out x, out y)
```

Note that you need to use the `out` keyword so that a pointer to the output variables is passed to the native code. You do need to use `out` or `ref` to make sure that the calling code sees the modified values.

Also note that the native function does not return a value. It's just a coincidence that the return value is passed through a register which by chance happened to contain the result of the last calculation that was performed.

Comment: I did what you suggested @David, still get the same answers.

Comment: It might help if you told us which compiler you use for the fortran

Comment: First I used the out modifier and no change in the results, then I used ref and out as you mentioned and the results changed to 0, 0 and an eight-digit number like 14394268!!!! Funny thing this number changes every time I run the code. I use Compaq Visual FORTRAN

Comment: Problem Solved, I added '!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: X,Y  ' to my FORTRAN code and used the out modifier in c# code and I got the right results. Thank you @David

Comment: Yes I realised from your first comment that the intent of out did not imply a reference as we both anticipated. Hence the request for compiler details. But I've been out since then and haven't had a chance to dig deeper. Well done for beating me to it. I'll update the answer in due course.